# When opening an executable using explorer.exe, how do I pass arguments to the executable?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

This is closely related to a solution to another question of mine: [How to invoke Windows' gvim in a Windows environment from within Cygwin?](https://superuser.com/questions/626440/how-to-invoke-windows-gvim-in-a-windows-environment-from-within-cygwin)

I've now found that giving `explorer.exe 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe'` in the Cygwin command-line opens Windows' gVim in a Windows context properly. I've written a `gvim` function in my .bashrc that executes the above command when called without arguments. However, I'd like to know how I can pass on the arguments to the gVim if the function is called *with* arguments. Trying `explorer.exe 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe' D:\myfile.txt` just opens Windows Explorer to the Libraries page, so this direct syntax doesn't work, but I'm unable to find what the correct way to pass these arguments is.
Googling only gives me the list of switches to explorer.exe but nothing about passing arguments to executables executed with explorer.exe.

**Edit**: Please note that I'm running this from Cygwin, and I've tried many of the more straightforward solutions before landing on using `explorer.exe`, as documented in the question linked at the top. `cygstart` and `cmd.exe /c` both leave remnants of the Cygwin environment within the opened gVim, which causes some issues as mentioned there.

Comment: Did you try using `start`? I think its entire purpose in life is to do what you're trying to coax Explorer into doing.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'm sorry, I don't understand, which `start` are you referring to? Cygwin doesn't seem to know a command called `start`, how do I use it?

Comment: Michael meant the `start` command from the Windows command-prompt. Obviously that’s not going to work from the cygwin command-prompt, but you should be able to make it work as I will demonstrate in a moment below…

Comment: @Synetech Yes, that's the one.

Comment: Try using just `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe' D:\myfile.txt` (i.e. leave off the `explorer.exe`. Alternatively, try `cmd.exe 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe' D:\myfile.txt`.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm running it from Cygwin so the first one doesn't work, and the second one (with the `/c` switch as required) doesn't give me the full Windows context, as explained in the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I found to achieve this was to create a batch file containing the call for the executable with the parameters and then running the batch file using explorer.exe. In this case, the batch file runs in the context of the explorer process and everything it runs stays in the same context. It means to create a batch file, let's call it `c:\activate.bat` and to put inside that file the call `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe' D:\myfile.txt`. Once the file exists it can be called using explorer.exe `%windir%\explorer.exe c:\activate.bat`. In my case, I also deleted the file afterward but that's not necessary.

Comment: You might consider clarifying with an example too.

Comment: @yuval-perelman: What file did you delete?

Comment: @Moberg c:\activate.bat