# Unable to use vim-fugitive when running Windows gvim from Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gvim

I'm running Windows version gvim from Cygwin which I have set up an alias in my bashrc based on this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/626743/223087):

`alias gvim="HOME=/c/Users/user cygstart /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/vim/vim74/gvim.exe"`

My _vimrc and _gvimrc works fine when gvim is started from cygwin.

However when using vim-fugitive I get this error:

```
/bin/bash -c "git --git-dir="D:/documents/.git" status"
The system cannot find the path specified.
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

Any suggestions to how to get vim-fugitive running in gvim started from cygwin?